# How do I script a filecount in android shell?

Tags: bash, adb

I am trying to script a filecount for various folders on an android phone

In a perfect world, the following should work

`adb shell ls -l | wc -l /sdcard/dcim/Camera`

In my head, that should output the filecount of ./sdcard/dcim/camera

But of course it doesn't, instead it says

`The term 'wc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
 of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:21
+ adb shell ls -l | wc <<<<  -l /sdcard/dcim/Camera
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

I can do `adb shell ls -l /sdcard/dcim/Camera` just fine

but as soon as I add the `| wc -l` part it breaks.

Any idea of what I'm missing here?

*Note: Yes, I could enter shell, navigate to the folder and then do it from there, but that is not the solution I am looking for today.*

Edit: when I do `adb shell "ls -l | wc -l" /sdcard/dcim/Camera` i get

`wc: /sdcard/dcim/Camera: Is a directory
0 /sdcard/dcim/Camera`

EDIT2:
I can't run wc in windows powershell, however, I can run it in androids shell, so

`adb shell "ls -l | wc -l"`

outputs the filecount in the phones root without the need for actually entering shell.

However, I have yet to discover how to do this in sub-folders.

Comment: Does `adb shell ls -l /sdcard/dcim/Camera | wc -l` work for you?

Comment: Nope, should have added that.
I'm going to try with some random "", it is probably something stupid that I just can't see right now.

Comment: What are the results when you run the command @devnull suggested? This command works for me when I run it from a terminal on a device running Android 4.2 and adb version 1.0.31.

Comment: The term 'wc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
 of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:41
+ adb shell ls -l /sdcard/dcim/Camera | wc <<<<  -l
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (wc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: What are you using to run the adb command? I ask because I have never seen adb output an error like that. The error `The term 'wc' is not recognized...` makes me think `wc` is not in your PATH on your local machine.

Comment: I was googling your error and it seemed people who had this type of error were running ADB on a windows machine. Assuming that is true, the  `adb shell ls -l /sdcard/dcim/Camera` will run and return the list of files in the Camera directory. The `| wc -l` part of the command *should* read in what `ls -l` returns. However, `wc -l` is not a standard command in the windows shell.

Comment: I'm running on windows 7 through Powershell and the wc command works fine when I try eg. adb shell wc -l /path..., the only problem is when pipeing (whatever the correct grammatical version of that is I don't know...) it after ls

Comment: ah, saw your comment after posting.
Well, this isn't the first time doing things like this on windows has been a problem. I'll see if I can find another approach instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are working within Power Shell on windows and the linux utility `wc` is not available, one possible solution is to do the following:

1. Download the BusyBox binary, specifically busybox-armv5 from [here](http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.21.1/).
2. Push busybox to the phone and install it.

   - `adb push path/to/busybox-armv5 /data/local/tmp`
   - `adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox-armv5`
   - `adb shell /data/local/tmp/busybox-armv5 --install .`
3. There should be a bunch of binaries in the /data/local/tmp directory. Pull off `wc` to your local machine.

   - `adb shell pull /data/local/tmp/wc /my/destination`

Now that you have the `wc` binary, you can use it in your Power Shell script as a resource by doing the following:

1. Before you run the adb command to get the file count, push the `wc` binary to /data/local/tmp. Make it executable.

   - `adb shell /path/to/wc /data/local/tmp/wc`
   - `adb shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/wc`
2. Now run your adb file count command.

   - `adb shell "ls -l /sdcard/dcim/Camera | /data/local/tmp/wc -l"`

Note: Putting quotes around the `ls` and `wc` command will ensure both commands are ran on the device. If the quotes were not there, only the command before the pipe would be ran on the device, while the `wc` command would be ran/interpreted by the power shell.

Answer (score 0):

If `/system/bin/busybox` exists, then the following should work:

```
adb shell ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera | busybox wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue as well. for getting a count on powershell you can do it like this:

```
$counter = $(adb shell 'ls sdcard/DCIM/Camera | wc -l') -as [int]
```